# Why is yarn link searching for the linked package in project folder+link folder

Tags: package, yarnpkg, symlink

I am trying to link a package into a project. In the package folder I executed: `yarn link`.

Then in my project folder I executed: `yarn link <package name>`.

But now when I start my project, yarn is looking for the package in 'project path + link path'.

So in my case I get following error:

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: Cannot parse C:\Projects\my-project\C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link\my-package\package.json as JSON: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Projects\my-project\C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link\my-package\package.json'
```

Does anyone have an idea why yarn is concatenating the project path and the link path and looking for the package at this place instead of just the link path?

Comment: I removed the yarn tag, and you added it back. May I ask how this question relates to YARN as in the Apache Hadoop component?

Answer (score 0):

I had had same issue. I simply solved it with `yarn unlink` then execute `yarn link` will get an output You can now run `yarn link "whatever-you-named-your-package"`. Get the directory that you wanna use in and execute yarn link "whatever-you-named-your-package"

Comment: I did exactly that but it is not working...I get the same error :(

Comment: @ChristophHummler you can try directly npm publish and testing it. This way is not a good way and you can test and npm unpublished -f then release last one.